# Certificate - How they get dealed out?

Tags: https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am interested in web security right now. So I read about PKI and Diffie Hellman authentication forms.

Now I am reading about certificates and I ask me how that works. So I know Browser have some trusted certificates in it, so you trust the pages, the company which the browser is from, trusts already. So when A trusts B and B trusts C --> A trusts C. Standart Web-of-trust thing.

But what I don't get is how for example google did it when they made there applications https. I never had to download a certificate. How works that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of commercial bodies whose business is the issuance of digital certificates; these are called "Certificate Authorities" or CAs. The certificates of the top-level keys of these bodies are distributed with the common web browsers, so you will already have them installed.

If you (or Google, or anyone else) want a certificate for your key you send a request (and some money) to one of the well-known CAs. The CA performs some checks to verify that you are who you say you are, and (as long as the checks check out) they make a new certificare by signing your key with their certificate-signing key.

When you send your certificate to some third party they can check your certificate using the CA's certificate stored in their browser, and this allows them to establish that the identity you claim in your certificate is correct.

There are various levels of certificate which carry different levels of guarantee that the identity claimed in the certificate is correct. Basically, the more you pay the more trouble the CA takes in checking your identity and the more insurance they buy!

Answer (score 0):

All browsers store certificates of [Certification Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority), who in turn issue certificates for various organizations.